# Border of each UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

[image]

I have to create something similar to above mentioned image. I have a view and i need border after eat view like {breakfast, brunch,etc..}

for giving border I was have following code.

```
CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 43.0f, menuHeadView.frame.size.width, 1.0f);
bottomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8f
                                                 alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
[menuHeadView.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];
```

it works fine for single view but if I have an array for those views and I want to have border after each view using indexPath it doesn't work since it doesn't allow

```
[array objectAtIndex:i].layer;
```

help please! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have array of views you probably should cast:
Change :

```
[array objectAtIndex:i].layer;
```

To:

```
((UIView*)[array objectAtIndex:i]).layer;
```

**EDIT:**
Based on **@Mischa** comment:

Casting is telling the array what object is in it. If you have different kind of objects in array (you really shouldn't!) or to be super safe you can change casting to assign:

```
id myUnknownObject = [array objectAtIndex:i];
if([myUnknownObject isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
   ((UIView*)myUnknownObject).layer...
} else {
   NSLog(@"%@",[myUnknownObject class]);
}
```

But base on your comment you contain `NSStrings` in your array so you can't add `layer` to this objects. Please check your console, it's probably `NSString`.

Of course since you mentioned indexPath, and if you're using TableView with rows. You should use the good stuff from reusability and it method:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    NSDictionary *cellDic = [self.heartbeats objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        //here goes reusability part like styling and stuff, this will calling only once for every reusable cell. So for example for cells height 44 this will called only 13 times for iPhone screen.

       //HERE you should manipulate with layer!
    }
    //here goes your custom text of every cell - like "Breakfast", "Brunch" and so on. This will calls for every row which is about to show up. 

      //HERE you should manipulate with text

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: A little more information about the "why": `((UIView*)[array objectAtIndex:i])` is a type cast. You need this aditional `(UIView*)` in front because an array doesn't know about the class of the objects it holds. E.g. you can add a `UIView` as the first element of an array and a `NSString` as the second element. So when extracting the objects from an array you need to tell the compiler of which class the corresponding object is.

Comment: hey thanks Man! but I'm not using uitable. They are individual views

Comment: I used your code like 
[((UIView*)[mealName objectAtIndex:i]).layer addSublayer:bottomBorder1];

but its giving a thread "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString layer]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: That's what @Mischa explained in first comment.

Comment: but i have also added (UIView*) still issue.

Comment: I updated my answer, show us an adding to array code in your question then we can help.

Comment: for (int i=0; i<[mealName count]; i++) {
        meal1Name = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, temp, 320, 35)];
[mealViewArray addObject:meal1Name];}